# JQuery mobile / input text in listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have several input fields which are inside a listview entry. So now i´m trying
to style the CSS of the input fields in such a way that it looks like a normal listview entry.

The input field will be filled out by angular´s ng-model, but this is not really important.

This is what i did so far, but i think i need help with margin/padding etc.

```
// CSS input
.ui-input-text{ 
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color : transparent;
}

// HTML
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b">
<li data-role="list-divider">Verbraucher</li>
<li data-mini="true"> <a href="#">
// This should look like a "normal" listview entry!
<input type="text" ng-model="cust.firstname" name="cust_firstname" required>    
</a></li>
...
```

[image: listview]

Both should look like the same!

Comment: what exact help do you need?

Comment: We are not understanding your query, can u put some code or set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following into your css:

```
.ui-input-listview {
  margin-top: -1em !important;
  margin-bottom: -1em !important;
  margin-left: -0.5em !important; /* If you want to fix left as well */
  margin-right: -0.5em !important; /* If you want to fix right as well */
}
```

And then, for the input in the listview, set the class to ui-input-listview

```
<input class="ui-input-listview" type="text" ng-model="cust.firstname" name="cust_firstname" required="required">
```

jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/EnF2w/1/